# Atribuir valor a uma variável em assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86

Possuo a variável:

```
simbolo db "0 $"
```

e tenho também a seguinte função:

```
  read_keyboard:
  mov ah, 1
  int 21h
  ret
```

Que é uma simples interrupção que lê do telado, e salva o que foi lido em **AH**.

O meu problema é: como eu consigo carregar o conteúdo de **AH** (lido do teclado) na minha variável **simbolo**?

já tentei:

```
mov simbolo, [AH]
```

e também

```
lea simbolo, AH
```

E não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `int 21,1` retorna o caracter lido no registrador `AL` (e não no `AH`).

Para carregar o valor do registrador `AL` na posição de memória `simbolo`, utilize o comando:

```
mov     [simbolo],al
```

- O colchete indica que `simbolo` é uma posição de memória.
- A origem (registrador `al`) fica a direita da vírgula, e o destino (`simbolo`) à esquerda, conforme a [sintaxe Intel](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_montagem_x86#Sintaxe).

*OBS: a sintaxe desse comando pode mudar dependendo do montador que você estiver utilizando.*

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado @Gomiero, deu tudo certo.
Mas eu li em alguns locais dizendo que a interrupção deveria ser feita da maneira que fiz, utilizando na primeira linha o `mov ah, 1`. Poderia me explicar o porque devo utilizar essa linha? Já que o que é lido é armazenado em `AL`.

Comment: @D_Alves De nada! O valor no registrador `AH`, setado **antes** da chamada da interrupção, corresponde à função que será chamada. Após a interrupção, o resultado é obtido no registrador `AL`. Cada função do DOS tem um número (sempre colocado em `AH`) e pode: receber parâmetros e/ou retornar resultados em outros registradores. Segue um link (em inglês) com a relação das chamadas, com os parâmetros e retornos: http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html